# Юнити. Realistic Car Controller, AI Controller

Tags: unity3d

уже не знаю, где найти ответ, может, кто сталкивался. Вообщем, есть префаб Багги из RCC, с измененной 3д моделькой, при управлении с клавиатуры в пустом проекте, где только эта машинка, она ездит отлично(вроде). Хотел сделать, чтобы она ездила сама по маршруту, в RCC это есть. Создал трассу, по ней расставил waypoint'ы, как указано, через Shift + LMB. Отображаются, все нормально. На машинку повесил AI Controller также из RCC. При запуске машинка начинает ехать куда-то вперед вправо, не реагируя на точки, хотя в Инспекторе, в скрипте AI Controller иногда показывается что машинка проехала какую то точку. Если взять сцену RCC Unity UFPS, где реализовано движение по маршруту, и поставить туда машинку, и указать массив объектов точек из данной сцены, по ним машинка едет, как только ставлю ее обратно к себе на сцену, и указываю свой массив - машинка едет не по маршруту, а как я писал выше, вперед вправо. Прилагаю фото Inspector машинки, фото Inspector массива и
фото сцены сверху под углом. Надеюсь, все понятно объяснил.
[image: Машинка(1)] [image: Машинка(2)][image: Массив(1)][image: Сцена сверху(1)]

Comment: А как поведет себя  машинка, если её запихнуть под  пустой объект и уже на него повесить AI Controller?

Comment: Может на вашей сцене не хватает NavMesh?

Comment: Сейчас все проверю, отпишусь.

Comment: В пустой объект просто так не запихнуть, нужно перетаскивать с машинки все скрипты, они как то взаимосвязаны друг с другом и не работают порознь. NavMesh не понимаю, как добавить, да и вроде он не нужен он. Сравнил просто с демо сценой, не нашел там нигде NavMesh.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал пересоздать машинку. Эффект тот же. Скопировал машинку с демо сцены, вставил к себе, и массив добавил свой. Ведет себя также. Может, я как то неправильно массив создал? Может ему кроме скрипта нужно что то еще?)

Comment: Массив точек идентичен по структуре массиву из демо сцены. Судя по всему, раз машинка работает на массиве из демо сцены, я как то неправильно создал его.

Comment: еще раз спрашиваю - помимо точек как работает поиск пути от точки до точки? используется NavMesh? Если так, то вероятно в демонстрационной сцене навмеш "запечен", а в созданной Вами самостоятельно - навмеш отсутствует

Comment: Дело скорее всего не в сцене. Ведь даже если я оставлю объект в своей сцене в иерархии, но перетащу его на поверхность сцены, машина едет. Но только с демонстрационными массивами. Пробую что то изменить, добавить - все сразу перестает работать, либо работает, но не так как надо.

Comment: Как именно работает поиск пути, мне не понятно

Comment: @Александр Даниловский Залез в скрипт, просмотрел, действительно, NavMesh используется. Если дело в NavMesh, как его добавить в мою сцену?

Comment: Разобрался, сейчас попробую добавить NavMesh, и поработать с ним. Спасибо

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое. Могу поставить вам галочку?

Comment: Сами напишите ответ, как вы нашли решение, как добавили навмеш и пр. И потом поставите галочку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена благодаря  Александру Даниловскому, не было компонента NavMesh на поверхностях сцены, на которых ездила машина. Чтобы добавить компонент NavMesh, нужно [отсюда](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents) скачать архив, в нем из папки Assets распаковать в папку с проектом, лучше также в Assets, затем появится нужные вам скрипты. Нужно будет на поверхность, где будет двигаться объект, добавить скрипт NavMeshSurface, и, выставив нужные настройки, "запечь"(нажать кнопку bake). А на объекте должен быть компонент NavMeshAgent.